# My usual confusion about "Either... or" meaning

Tags: either-or

I've been asked to submit a proposal for a project "by outlining it in either a) a Logframe or b) a Theory of Change model".

Does the sentence mean I have to choose between a) and b), or does it mean I have to send both, a) AND b)?

This "in either"... makes me feel uncertain about the exact meaning!

Comment: I don't know how your teacher could have been more explicit and unambiguous than using "*either ... or*". But if you really do still have doubts, you should be asking her, not us.

Comment: This is not ambiguous. Perhaps you have at the back of your mind a **potential** ambiguity, as with 'Show how P may be outlined either in a Logframe or a Theory of Change model', where 'either' may refer either to how P may be outlined ( 'P may be outlined either in a Logframe or a Theory of Change model. Show that this is so.'), or how you may show how P may be outlined  ('Show how P may be outlined. [You may do this using either a Logframe or a Theory of Change model]').

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should have in mind three closely related forms:

1. Both a and b

   This is positive for a and for b.

Exp: I'd like both apples and oranges = I want the two of them

2. Either a or b

   One among the two

Exp: I'd like to have either apples or oranges = I am Asking for one of them. It doesn't really matter which.

3. Neither a nor b

   Not one, not the other

Exp: I'd like neither apples nor oranges = I don't want apples and I don't want oranges.

In your case you can pick the one you prefer.